# How to combine GitLab CI job for rule:if with matrix and allow_failure?

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline

I need configure my GitLab CI job like this:

1. Only job with `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"` is added to Pipeline,
2. Job is runned multipletimes by `matrix` for each version defined by matrix `PHP_VERSION: [ '7.4', '8.0', '8.1' ]`.
3. The `'8.1'` must but runned with `allow_failure: true`.

I tried to write rules *intuitive* as I except rules works, but I'm getting a different result.

I first tried this:

```yaml
parallel:
matrix:
  - PHP_VERSION: [ '7.4', '8.0', '8.1' ]
rules:
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    when: on_success
  - if: '$PHP_VERSION == "8.1"'
    allow_failure: true
```

It result only to MR event for PHP 8.1 us added to Pipeline.

My next iteration is still wrong:

```yaml
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PHP_VERSION: [ '7.4', '8.0', '8.1' ]
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: on_success
    - if: '$PHP_VERSION == "8.1"'
      when: on_success
      allow_failure: true
    - when: on_success
```

This looks better, but it runs job for every other event (not only `merge_request_event`).

How I can to right combine rules to get result as I declared above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try

```
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PHP_VERSION: [ '7.4', '8.0', '8.1' ]
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: on_success
    - if: '$PHP_VERSION == "8.1"'
      when: on_success
      allow_failure: true
    - if: '$PHP_VERSION'
      when: on_success
      allow_failure: false
```

Based on https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-a-matrix-of-parallel-trigger-jobs

Example of execution

[image]

Comment: Updated answer, did not add full answer

Comment: Thanks! I have question: Why I need to repeat list of **all** PHP versions in `rule:if` statement? It's violated the DRY principle.

Comment: The reason that i added this is that this rule has to trigger for all PHP versions if you add only one version the job won't trigger. I didn't test if you just add  - if: '$PHP_VERSION'

With the logic to test only that the PHP_VERSION variable is defined

Comment: Just tested it should also work like this, so you wont need to add all versions. Updated answer

Comment: Ah, next question: variable `$allow_failure` cannot be set to `boolean` value, only `string|int` allowed. I tried to replace it to `0`/`1`, but now is failing using of these var at: `allow_failure: $allow_failure` because it's allow put `boolean` only. Can i use something like a `allow_failure: ($allow_failure == 1)` to convert var to bool?

Comment: you are correct, it wont allow booleans. You cant add this ```allow_failure: ($allow_failure == 1)```  . Because Gitlab variables wont interpret as a command. Updating the answer again, with something that should work that is semi elegant

Comment: Your newer update has same result as I exampled at origin post: Only PHP 8.1 job run, others doesn't.  OMG, I think the origin question looks simple but unrelizable in GitLab CI, maybe.

Comment: mm that it seems weird, I added a picture on how it looks on GUI. Maybe did it mislead you since it shows only one job?

Comment: Is there any chance that you are on self hosted? What Gitlab version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> This looks better, but it runs job for every other event (not only merge_request_event).

If you want to run *only* on merge request, you have to invert the logic:

```
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
```